# ios - multi facebook account on one device

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-share

I'm having an iOS app, need Facebook login to share something to wall. Everything is ok until I received new feedback from customer. Let me describe this case.
Apple have integrated Facebook into iOS system, user just needs to login via Setting, it is so easy for user. But my customer does not want to do that, they want user to login Facebook inside app and use it instead of Facebook of iOS system. Problem is here, there is a case: user has already logged in Facebook account A via iOS system, then user opens app and login Facebook inside app with other Facebook account B. After that, user shares a picture. Requiment is this picture should be shared on wall of Facebook account B (of app), but this picture appeared on wall of Facebook account A(of iOS system). 
I just wonder do we have any solutions to resolve this case? Please give me any ideas you all have in mind after reading.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with Facebook SDK whenever a user login from any app using Facebook it change userid returned with the token which leads to share on the latest opened account.

if you open Facebook from a browser you will get this message from Facebook " we got confused please re-login "

so i took the same approach i saved user-id User(A) and whenever user share i check id coming with token if it changed i show " Facebook account changed please relogin " & i log all users out.

check this link may be helpful: https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10205949056147843